# Regex to match a string having escaped characters

Tags: regex, string-matching

I want to write a regular expression which can match following specification for string literals. For the last 10 hours, I've gone crazy over formulating various regular expressions which none seem to work. Finally I've boiled down to this one:

- `([^"]|(\\[.\n]))*\"`

Basically, requirements are following:

1. A String literal has to be matched so I'm matching everything upto the last ", in between there could be a \", which should not end the string.
2. We could also be able to escape anything including a \n with a '\'
3. Only an **unescaped** '"' character can end the match, nothing else.

Some sample strings which I need to correctly match are following:

1. \a\b\"\n" => I should match following character '\', 'a', '\', 'b', '\','"','\', 'n', '"'
2. \"this is still inside the string" => should match whole text including last '"'
3. 'm about to escape to a newline \'\n'" => There's a \n character in this string, but still the string should match everything from starting 'm' to ending '"'.

Kindly someone please help me formulate such a Regex. In my opinion that Regex I've provided should do the job, but it's rather failing for no reason.

Comment: I fail to understand as to why there is not a fixed recipe for this problem. This is a standard problem. In every programming language, we need to match string literals in some fashion, and usually we allow a lot of freedom with \ escape sequences. There should be some general recipe (standard regular expression) to achieve this effect. However, I failed to find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression is almost right, you just need to be aware that inside a character class the period `.` is just a literal `.` and not *any character except newline*. So:

```
([^"\\]|\\(.|\n))*\"
```

Or:

```
([^"\\]|\\[\s\S])*\"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this would be more efficient:

```
[^"\\]*(\\.[^"\\]*)*\"
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that your string also starts with a " (Should your examples not start with it?)

The Lookaround construct seems most natural for me to use:

```
".*?"(?<!\\")
```

Given the input

```
"test" test2 "test \a test"  "test \"test" "test\""
```

this will match:

```
"test"
"test \a test"
"test \"test"
"test\""
```

The regex reads:

```
Match the character “"” literally «"»
Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character “"” literally «"»
Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below with the match ending at this position (negative lookbehind) «(?<!\\")»
   Match the character “\” literally «\\»
   Match the character “"” literally «"»
```

Comment: What language are you using the regex in?

Comment: Regex Rule of Thumb #37: If it seems natural, you're probably doing it wrong. :D  Almost everyone comes up with this approach at some time or other, but it fails if the last thing before the closing quote is an escaped backslash--e.g, `"test\\"`.

Comment: I'm using lex, whereby I have to define the rules for the regex. The problem is that I want to match a string literal. Once I match it, I further process it. I already match the starting ", whereby after I have to match the remaining stirng, which may include anything on this planet, except an unescaped double-quote. Somehow, I'm not able to do it.